# Assign specific data to a variable from a text file

Tags: c, text-files, variable-assignment

cant seem to find anywhere on the internet where theres an example on how to assign a variable with numbers from a text file.
Lets say we have a text line that goes like this

222 333 3242 33231 34123 32321

If i want to assign a variable to lets say 34123, how do i do it?

Comment: Kinda what I've been doing but i cant find anything on it, if you  dont want to help then dont post crap?

Comment: So what have you done so far in regards of coding.

Comment: I meant in coding a solution to your question. Anway did you read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: My god, are you that bored? Im working on a program atm where i scan info from a text file into my program, and i just dont know how to make some of the "info" inside the text file a variable.

Comment: The program works with just reading and printing it out when i run the program, but i need to only find  certain info in the file, and with that i need to make a variable thats assigned to some info in the text file, no?

Answer (score 2):

You may use [fscanf](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/scanf)

e.g./

```
int main()
{
  int i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6;

  FILE *my_stream;
  char my_filename[] = "exciting_numbers.txt";
  my_stream = fopen (my_filename, "r");

  fscanf (my_stream, "%i %i %i %i %i %i", &i1, &i2, &i3, &i4, &i5, &i6);

  fclose (my_stream);
}
```

If you don't know how many integers you want to read in, then you could do something similar for one integer within a loop that will break when EOF is found?

Comment: I follow you, but what if i want something between specific columns in my lines?

Comment: That's a different question from above?  How do you determine the different columns?

Comment: Well they are all splitted by "space" and theres 6 different words/numbers, im just not sure how to get them into my program as a variable

Comment: Probably best if you modify your question to reflect what you're actually after, or start a new one, then I'll attempt to answer? :)  Maybe just the case you need to use %s in the scanf, and then check if it's a number?